# superimposing two probability plots with probplot

Tags: r, plot, label, probability, axis

I can create a lognormal probability plot using the `probplot()` function from the `e1071` package.  A problem arises when I try to add another set of lognormal data to the first plot.  Although I use the command `par(new=T)`, the xaxis of the two plots are different and don't align.

Is there another way to go about this?

I tried using the `points()` function.  However, it appears I need the x and y coordinates to plot it and I don't know how to extract the x, y coordinates from the `probplot()` function.

''' R

```
# Program to plot random logn failure times with probability plot

library(e1071)

logn_prob_plot <- function() {
  set.seed(1)
  x<-rlnorm(10,1,1)

  par(bty="l")

  par(col.lab="white")
  p<-probplot(x,qdist=qlnorm)
  par(col.lab="black")

  mtext(text="failure time", col="black",side=1,line=3,outer=F)
  mtext(text="lognormal probability", col="black",side=2,line=3,outer=F)

  set.seed(2)
  y=rlnorm(10,2,3)
  par(new=T)

  par(col.lab="white")
  probplot(y,qdist=qlnorm,xlab="fail time",ylab="lognormal probability")
  par(col.lab="black")

  mtext(text="failure time", col="black",side=1,line=3,outer=F)
  mtext(text="lognormal probability", col="black",side=2,line=3,outer=F)
}

logn_prob_plot()
```

My expected result is two groups of data on the same probability plot with the same x and y axes.  Instead, I get two different x-axes that are not aligned.

[image: two lognormal data sets on same plot]

Comment: Your code is comparing both simulated samples to a lognormal distribution with meanlog = 0, sdlog = 1. Is this what you want?

Comment: No, one set of data has a mean of 1 and a sigma of 1, the variable "x".  The variable y has a mean of 2 and a sigma of 3.

Comment: I this case what you want is
p<-probplot(x,qdist=qlnorm, meanlog = 1, sdlog = 1) for the first one and
q <- probplot(y,qdist=qlnorm,meanlog = 2, sdlog = 3)

Comment: Thanks Grada.  I tried that and got the same result.  The x-axis of the two groups of data use a different scale.  Is there a way for me to use the points() function?  How would I get the y-values for use with points()?

Comment: Yes it is possible just give me some time. The question was about the distributions not about the plot. Adding the correct parameters wouldnot have solved your problem. I just needed to know which ones should I work with. Draw  q <- probplot(y,qdist=qlnorm) if you want to see why

Answer (score 0):

First lets simulate the variables:

```
 set.seed(1)
 x<-rlnorm(10,1,1)

 set.seed(2)
 y=rlnorm(10,2,3)
```

The first probplot is:

```
p<-probplot(x,qdist=qlnorm, meanlog = 1, sdlog = 1)
```

which produces the output:[image]

The second probplot is:

```
q <- probplot(y,qdist=qlnorm,meanlog = 2, sdlog = 3)
```

which produces the output:[image]

Your best shot a merging them is using the scale of the smaller one and discarding some points:

```
p<-probplot(x,qdist=qlnorm, meanlog = 1, sdlog = 1)
  points(sort(x), p[[1]](ppoints(length(x))),  col = "red", pch = 19)
 lines(q, col = "blue")
 points(sort(y), q[[1]](ppoints(length(y))),  col = "blue", pch = 19)
```

which gives:[image]

The red line and points are from the distribution with meanlog = 1, sdlog = 1 and the
blue ones are from the one with meanlog = 2, sdlog = 3.

I further have to warn you that from reading the code of the probplot() function:

```
    xl <- quantile(x, c(0.25, 0.75))
    yl <- qdist(c(0.25, 0.75), ...)
    slope <- diff(yl)/diff(xl)
```

the slope of the line is determined only by position the first and the third quartile and not bz what happens elsewhere.